# Provide space Between Words and Numbers in string using RegEx Replace function (C#)

Tags: c#, regex

```
Membernumber350005Calculationdate04/08/2015Casenumber880898Case0.12Amount546.3Fors
```

Here is a string containing words and digits(inluding date and decimal format) in it with no space between them. I want to give space between words and numbers. My output should be a string NOT an array and that should be this..

```
Membernumber 350005 Calculationdate 04/08/2015 Casenumber 880898 Case 0.12 Amount 546.3 Fors
```

I tried the below code. I have succeeded filtering date and decimal formats and giving space around them. but i am stuck in giving space around the words.

```
string s = "Membernumber350005Calculationdate04/08/2015Casenumber880898Case0.12Amount546.3Fors";
string SpaceAroundDate = Regex.Replace(s, @"(\d+/\d+/\d+)", @" $1 ");
string SpaceAroundDecimal = Regex.Replace(SpaceAroundDate, @"(\d+\.\d+)", @" $1 ");
```

With this code, i could make this,

```
Membernumber35000520Calculationdate 04/08/2015 Casenumber880898Case 0.12 Amount 546.3 fors
```

And then i wrote this to give space between the words and the numbers,

```
string SpaceAroundWord = Regex.Replace(SpaceAroundDecimal, @"([A-Za-z]\w+)([0-9]\d+)([A-Za-z]\w+)", @"$1 $2 $3");
```

But it doesn't work. Hope i have given enough information needed. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you do not have mixed formats for dates and floats, you can try `Regex.Replace(s, @"\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}|\d+(?:\.\d+)?", " $& ")`. [Demo here](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cd%7b2%7d%2f%5cd%7b2%7d%2f%5cd%7b4%7d%7c%5cd%2b(%3f%3a%5c.%5cd%2b)%3f&i=Membernumber350005Calculationdate04%2f08%2f2015Casenumber880898Case0.12Amount546.3Fors&r=+%24%26+).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go

```
string input = @"Membernumber350005Calculationdate04/08/2015Casenumber880898Case0.12Amount546.3Fors";
string result = Regex.Replace(input, @"([a-zA-Z]+|[0-9]+[0-9/\.]+[0-9]+)", "$& ");
```

Comment: To clarify: `/` is a literal `/`. To escape a special char, you need a *backslash* ``\``. You do not need to escape `.` inside a character class to denote a literal `.`. Moreover, this regex will enclose with spaces any `.` and `/` symbols, not only dates and numbers.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew ok now the date / time / amount has to start and end with a digit

Comment: The capturing groups is redundant here, you yourself are not using it since the `$0` refers to the whole match (I'd rather use `$&`, but it seems `$0` works as well). Also, you do not have to escape a `/` as it is not a special character in .NET regex.